# How to automatically update Firefox without interrupting the user?

Tags: firefox, software-updates

When Firefox gets updated via apt while it's running, the user gets prompted to restart the browser when they open a new page. How can I keep Firefox automatically updated while avoiding this issue? Would Flatpak work?

Comment: I would imagine that if the Firefox authors knew of a way to avoid a visible restart they would have already coded it

Comment: It also annoys me a lot. One option could be if Firefox would not force the immediate application of an update, but have an option to delay it e.g. to after the next Firefox startup.

Comment: That doesn't work because Firefox doesn't apply the update at all, the package manager does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flatpak does indeed appear to work.